# React Native - Native Modules iOS Empty

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-native-module

I am creating an iOS 14 widget for my app. The part of widget is working, but I want to create an Native integration for updating my widget data.

I started following this tutorial: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios

It is running (no compile errors) but the code is working like no method is being exposed.

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
...
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(NativeModules); // returning an empty object {} 
}, []);
```

I did not found if there was any change in the Native Modules that justify my code not being visible. I tried to rewrite sometimes to see if I have forgot anything.